# как передать json на сервер

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net

Здравствуйте, у меня есть 2 json объекта, находящиеся в javascript. Каким образом мне хранить их на сервере, файлами или в запросе передавать? Пожалуйста, с примерами кода.
Бэкэнд на ASP.NET 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На клиенте конвертировать его в `string`:

```
myStringObj = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

Дальше отправить его любым способом на сервер (xhr, form submit);
Процесс [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp)

А как хранить вам виднее, либо база данных, либо статичный json, зависит от того что делаете

Answer (score 0):

С фронтом всё просто , если есть JQuery то просто

```
    $.post("/xls",{'data' : 'data'},onAjaxSuccess)
onAjaxSuccess(data){
console.log('Всё ОК');
}
```

с бэкендом помочь несмогу, ASP.NET не знаю.